# BigQuery taking too much time on simple LEFT JOIN

Tags: join, google-bigquery, left-join

So I'm doing a really basic left join, basically joining different identifiers of my database, described below :

```
SELECT
main_id,
DT.table_1.mid_id AS mid_id,
final_id

FROM DT.table_1

LEFT JOIN DT.table_2 ON DT.table_1.mid_id = DT.table_2.mid_id
```

Table 1 is composed of four columns, main_id, mid_id, firstSeen and lastSeen.
There is 17,014,676 rows, for 519 MB of data. Each row is composed of a unique main_id - mid_id couple, but a main_id/mid_id can appear multiple times in the table.

Table 2 is composed of four columns, mid_id, final_id, firstSeen and lastSeen.
There is 66,779,079 rows, for 3.86 GB of data. In the same way, each row is composed of a unique mid_id - final_id couple, but a mid_id/final_id can appear multiple times in the table.

BigQuery is using only 3.11 GB for the query himself.
first_id and mid_id are integers, final_id is a string.

The Query result was too big for bigQuery to resolve so I had to create a "result" table, containing first, mid and final id with the exact type I wrote above. The "Allow Large Results" option had to be selected, or an error was thrown.

My problem is that this simple query already took an hour, and is not even finalised yet ! I read that the good practice would have been to do a RIGHT JOIN so that the first table in the join is the biggest, but still, an hour is awfully long, even for that case !

Do you, kind people of Stack Overflow, have an explanation ?

Thank you by advance !

Comment: Do you have skew in the data? See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-patterns#data_skew

Comment: Yes I'm pretty sure that's the problem ! 
I ran the data with R and it told me that there were more than 2^31 rows beign created, and using sample data and the above number the aproximation I came with predicted 30 billions rows ... I will filter the data a bit more I guess !

Thank you for you help !